# Removing values from a collection

Tags: vb.net

Here is my code

```
Public Class FrmGameBoard



Const NumValues As Integer = 26
Dim Values(NumValues) As Decimal
Dim ValueCollection = New Collection
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim Briefcases = New Collection
Dim RemainingBriefcases = New Collection
Dim GlobalAction As Integer = 0
Dim turn As Integer = 0
Dim name As String
Dim numberofremainingvalues, sumofremainingvalues As Integer
Dim MyValue, EVBig, EVSmall As Double
Dim n As Integer = 0
Function longif()

    If MyValue = 0.01 Then
        Lbl1p.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(0)
    ElseIf MyValue = 0.02 Then
        Lbl2p.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(1)
    ElseIf MyValue = 0.05 Then
        Lbl5p.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(2)
    ElseIf MyValue = 0.1 Then
        Lbl10p.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(3)
    ElseIf MyValue = 0.25 Then
        Lbl25p.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(4)
    ElseIf MyValue = 0.5 Then
        Lbl50p.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(5)
    ElseIf MyValue = 0.75 Then
        Lbl75p.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(6)
    ElseIf MyValue = 1.0 Then
        Lbl1d.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(7)
    ElseIf MyValue = 2.5 Then
        Lbl2d50p.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(8)
    ElseIf MyValue = 5.0 Then
        Lbl5d.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(9)
    ElseIf MyValue = 10.0 Then
        Lbl10d.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(10)
    ElseIf MyValue = 25.0 Then
        Lbl25d.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(11)
    ElseIf MyValue = 50.0 Then
        Lbl50d.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(12)
    ElseIf MyValue = 100.0 Then
        Lbl100d.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(13)
    ElseIf MyValue = 500.0 Then
        Lbl500d.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(14)
    ElseIf MyValue = 1000.0 Then
        Lbl1000d.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(15)
    ElseIf MyValue = 5000.0 Then
        Lbl5000d.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(16)
    ElseIf MyValue = 10000.0 Then
        Lbl10000d.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(17)
    ElseIf MyValue = 50000.0 Then
        Lbl50000d.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(18)
    ElseIf MyValue = 100000.0 Then
        Lbl100000d.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(19)
    ElseIf MyValue = 250000.0 Then
        Lbl250000d.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(20)
    ElseIf MyValue = 500000.0 Then
        Lbl500000d.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(21)
    ElseIf MyValue = 750000.0 Then
        Lbl750000d.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(22)
    ElseIf MyValue = 1000000 Then
        Lbl1000000d.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(23)
    ElseIf MyValue = 1250000.0 Then
        Lbl1250000d.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(24)
    ElseIf MyValue = 1500000.0 Then
        Lbl1500000.Visible = False
        RemainingBriefcases.Remove(25)
    End If
    turn = turn + 1
    LblTurnNumber.Text = CStr(turn)



End Function





Private Sub FrmGameBoard_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim X As Integer
    Dim n As Integer = 1


    Dim MyRandom As New Random()
    Values(0) = 0.01
    Values(1) = 0.02
    Values(2) = 0.05
    Values(3) = 0.1
    Values(4) = 0.25
    Values(5) = 0.5
    Values(6) = 0.75
    Values(7) = 1.0
    Values(8) = 2.5
    Values(9) = 5.0
    Values(10) = 10.0
    Values(11) = 25.0
    Values(12) = 50.0
    Values(13) = 100.0
    Values(14) = 500.0
    Values(15) = 1000.0
    Values(16) = 5000.0
    Values(17) = 10000.0
    Values(18) = 50000.0
    Values(19) = 100000.0
    Values(20) = 250000.0
    Values(21) = 500000.0
    Values(22) = 750000.0
    Values(23) = 1000000.0
    Values(24) = 1250000.0
    Values(25) = 1500000.0



    name = InputBox("Please enter your name below.")
    LblWelcome.Text = "Welcome " & name
    Do While i <= NumValues
        ValueCollection.Add(Values(i))
        RemainingBriefcases.Add(Values(i))
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    i = 1
    For n = 1 To NumValues
        X = MyRandom.Next(1, ValueCollection.Count)
        Briefcases.Add(ValueCollection(X))
        ValueCollection.Remove(X)
    Next
    n = 1
    i = 1


End Sub

Private Sub Lbl1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Lbl1.Click
    Const MyNumber As Integer = 1
    Lbl1.Visible = False
    Pic1.Visible = False
    MyValue = Briefcases(MyNumber)
    Dim action As Integer = 0
    If GlobalAction = 0 Then
        LblMyBriefcase.Text = CStr(MyNumber)
        action = 1
        GlobalAction = 1
    End If

    If action = 0 Then
        longif()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Pic1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Pic1.Click
    Const MyNumber As Integer = 1
    Lbl1.Visible = False
    Pic1.Visible = False
    MyValue = Briefcases(MyNumber)
    Dim action As Integer = 0
    If GlobalAction = 0 Then
        LblMyBriefcase.Text = CStr(MyNumber)
        action = 1
        GlobalAction = 1
    End If

    If action = 0 Then
        longif()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Lbl2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Lbl2.Click
    Const MyNumber As Integer = 2
    Lbl2.Visible = False
    Pic2.Visible = False
    MyValue = Briefcases(MyNumber)
    Dim action As Integer = 0
    If GlobalAction = 0 Then
        LblMyBriefcase.Text = CStr(MyNumber)
        action = 1
        GlobalAction = 1
    End If
    If action = 0 Then
        longif()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Pic2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Pic2.Click
    Const MyNumber As Integer = 2
    Lbl2.Visible = False
    Pic2.Visible = False
    Dim action As Integer = 0
    MyValue = Briefcases(MyNumber)
    If GlobalAction = 0 Then
        LblMyBriefcase.Text = CStr(MyNumber)
        action = 1
        GlobalAction = 1
    End If
    If action = 0 Then
        longif()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Lbl3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Lbl3.Click
    Const MyNumber As Integer = 3
    Lbl3.Visible = False
    Pic3.Visible = False
    Dim action As Integer = 0
    MyValue = Briefcases(MyNumber)
    If GlobalAction = 0 Then
        LblMyBriefcase.Text = CStr(MyNumber)
        action = 1
        GlobalAction = 1
    End If
    If action = 0 Then
        longif()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Pic3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Pic3.Click
    Const MyNumber As Integer = 3
    Lbl3.Visible = False
    Pic3.Visible = False
    Dim action As Integer = 0
    MyValue = Briefcases(MyNumber)
    If GlobalAction = 0 Then
        LblMyBriefcase.Text = CStr(MyNumber)
        action = 1
        GlobalAction = 1
    End If
    If action = 0 Then
        longif()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Lbl4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Lbl4.Click
    Const MyNumber As Integer = 4
    Lbl4.Visible = False
    Pic4.Visible = False
    Dim action As Integer = 0
    MyValue = Briefcases(MyNumber)
    If GlobalAction = 0 Then
        LblMyBriefcase.Text = CStr(MyNumber)
        action = 1
        GlobalAction = 1
    End If
    If action = 0 Then
        longif()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Pic4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Pic4.Click
    Const MyNumber As Integer = 4
    Lbl4.Visible = False
    Pic4.Visible = False
    Dim action As Integer = 0
    MyValue = Briefcases(MyNumber)
    If GlobalAction = 0 Then
        LblMyBriefcase.Text = CStr(MyNumber)
        action = 1
        GlobalAction = 1
    End If
    If action = 0 Then
        longif()
    End If
End Sub

   ............... (the same code just continues for the different picboxes     and labels up to 26)


End Class
```

I want to have the values of the remaining briefcases in the RemainingBriefcases Collection so I remove the selected value in the longif() function. However, it works for the first few clicks, but after a few it highlights one of the RemainingBriefcases.Remove statements and says Collection index must be in the range 1 to the size of the collection.
What should I change?
Thanks

Comment: The problem is probably that as you remove elements the size of the list gets shorter.  So then all of your indexes are wrong.

Comment: @Derek Is there a way I can get the new indexes?

Comment: You need to re-think how you're removing items. If you have a collection {1,2,3} and you remove the first item, you are left with {2,3}. Remove the second item and you are left with {2}. Can you see how it goes wrong?

Comment: @Andrew Thank you. That makes sense. Is there an "easy" way of removing the values then?

Comment: Is there a way to maybe remove items by their value instead of their index?

Comment: @JohnArg For a start, I think I would create a class named, say, "BriefCase", with properties such as the associated value, a reference to the label it uses, and a reference to the picturebox it uses. Then make a `List(Of Briefcase)`. That will enable you to have *one* method for *both* the Pic.Click and Lbl.Click events (you have the same code in each) - you can assign the handler for each pic and label with [AddHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx). It may take you a little while to adjust your code, but it will be worth it for the vast simplification it will give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my earlier comment, I created a new Windows Forms project. I added a label for "LblTurnNumber", a panel "pnlBriefcases" to show the briefcases, and a panel "valuesLabels" to show the values which have not been selected.

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Public Class FrmGameBoard

    Dim briefcases As List(Of Briefcase)
    Dim valuesLabels As List(Of Label)
    Dim clicksProcessed As Integer = 0

    Class Briefcase
        Property Value As Decimal
        Property AssociatedLabel As Label
        Property AssociatedPictureBox As PictureBox
        Property IsAvailable As Boolean = True

    End Class

    Private Sub Briefcase_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ' get the control which raised the event
        Dim ctrl = DirectCast(sender, Control)
        ' get the briefcase for that control
        Dim bc = DirectCast(ctrl.Tag, Briefcase)

        bc.AssociatedLabel.Visible = False
        bc.AssociatedPictureBox.Visible = False

        ' I don't know the purpose of the following line: I carried it over from the example oode
        '  referring to Briefcases vs. RemainingBriefcases 
        bc.IsAvailable = False

        ' Find the value in the available values corresponding to the item clicked on...
        Dim valueToRemove = bc.Value.ToString()
        Dim valueToHide = valuesLabels.First(Function(vl) vl.Text = valueToRemove)

        valueToHide.Visible = False

        clicksProcessed += 1
        LblTurnNumber.Text = clicksProcessed.ToString()

    End Sub

    Sub Init()
        Dim rand As New Random()
        Dim values() As Decimal = {0.01D, 0.02D, 0.05D, 0.1D, 0.25D, 0.5D, 0.75D, 1D, 2.5D, 5D, 10D, 25D, 50D, 100D, 500D, 1000D, 5000D, 10000D, 50000D, 100000D, 250000D, 500000D, 750000D, 1000000D, 1250000D, 1500000D}

        ' Create a set of labels showing the available values
        ' and show them in a panel named "valuesPanel".
        valuesLabels = New List(Of Label)

        For i = 0 To values.Length - 1
            Dim valueLabel As New Label With {.Text = values(i).ToString()}
            valueLabel.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight
            Dim yPos = valuesPanel.Height - 24 * (i + 1)
            valueLabel.Location = New Point(6, yPos)
            valuesPanel.Controls.Add(valueLabel)
            valuesLabels.Add(valueLabel)

        Next

        ' Get a shuffled list of the values
        Dim shuffledValues As New List(Of Decimal)
        For i = 0 To values.Length - 1
            shuffledValues.Insert(rand.Next(0, i), values(i))
        Next

        ' Create briefcases with imaages and labels
        ' and associate those to UI elements.

        briefcases = New List(Of Briefcase)

        For i = 0 To values.Count - 1
            Dim lbl As New Label
            Dim pb As New PictureBox

            ' N.B. The following is a crude and unsatisfactory way to display the briefcases and
            ' requires improvement.

            'TODO: set the text of lbl and the image of pb properly
            'TODO: set the position of lbl and the position of pb properly
            pb.Image = Bitmap.FromFile("C:\temp\briefcase.png")
            Dim xSize = pb.Image.Width
            Dim ySize = pb.Image.Height
            Dim xLoc = (i Mod 13) * xSize ' magic number 13 to make two rows of briefcases because there are 26 of them
            Dim yLoc = (i \ 13) * ySize + 40 ' magic number 40 to crudely account for label size

            pb.Size = pb.Image.Size
            pb.Location = New Point(xLoc, yLoc)
            lbl.Location = New Point(xLoc, yLoc + ySize)

            lbl.Text = "???" & i.ToString()

            ' Tell it what to do when the Label or PictureBox is clicked...
            AddHandler lbl.Click, AddressOf Briefcase_Click
            AddHandler pb.Click, AddressOf Briefcase_Click

            ' Show the controls we have created...
            pnlBriefcases.Controls.Add(lbl)
            pnlBriefcases.Controls.Add(pb)

            ' Create a Briefcase which has a value and is connected to the label and picturebox:
            Dim thisBriefcase = New Briefcase With {.Value = shuffledValues(i), .AssociatedLabel = lbl, .AssociatedPictureBox = pb}

            ' Connect the label and picturebox to the Briefcase
            ' - the .Tag holds an Object, i.e. anything we want as long as we know what to convert it back to when we use it.
            lbl.Tag = thisBriefcase
            pb.Tag = thisBriefcase

            briefcases.Add(thisBriefcase)

        Next

        LblTurnNumber.Text = clicksProcessed.ToString()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Init()

    End Sub

End Class
```

The image "C:\temp\briefcase.png" is

[image]

Starting the program shows:

[image]

(I did say it needed improvements for the UI...)
and after clicking a few pictureboxes/labels...

[image]

If you need to process the briefcases which are still displayed, you can get a list of them with something like

```
Dim stillShown = briefcases.Where(Function(bc) bc.IsAvailable).ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It's perfect1

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim briefcases As List(Of Double) = New List(Of Double)
briefcases.Add( 1.0 ) 
briefcases.Add( 2.0 ) 
briefcases.Add( 3.0 )
briefcases.Remove( 2.0 )
```

This will let you remove items by number.